# Detecting mousewheel without focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, mousewheel

I have an element which becomes visible when hovered over. When focused, it also responds to mousewheel events.

Naturally, the on hover event works even when the element's window does not have focus. This gives the impression that the element can be interacted with. However, the element does not respond to any mousewheel events unless the window is focused.

Is it possible to get the mousewheel events to the hovered element without the user manually focusing the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty browser dependent, and I think you're browser is getting it wrong. It shouldn't be responding to hover events either if its window isn't focused. I know my browser certainly doesn't behave that way.

There's no way to compensate, if your scroll wheel events aren't being fired you can't *force* the browser to behave differently than it is.

Comment: Fair enough. Just thought I'd check if there was something. :)